# How, or is it possible, to execute a java app from an unzipped jar

Tags: java, jar

How, or is it possible, to execute a java app from an unzipped jar.  I have unzipped a jar file using 7zip.  I found the MANIFEST.MF file and made note of the Main-Class: path which is "com.uwsoft.editor.LevelEditor".  I am now trying to execute the unzipped java app by navigating to the directory in the console, which contains the "LevelEditor.class" file, and running the command "java LevelEditor" in the console.  I get the error "Error: Unable to find or load main class LevelEditor".  I can successfully execute the jar file from the console and I can even repackage the jar file and execute it. I am hoping I can that I can execute the app without repackaging it.  Please excuse the noob question, I'm a .net developer new to java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move up three folders from there, so

```
cd ..\..\..\
```

to the folder that contains `com`. Then

```
java -cp . com.uwsoft.editor.LevelEditor
```

Because java packages correspond to folders in the file-system. To quote [What Is a Package?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html)

> Conceptually you can think of packages as being similar to different folders on your computer.

Comment: What am I doing wrong here? `e:\Software\Overlap2D_006\Overlap2D>java -cp . com.uwsoft.editor.LevelEditor
Error: Could not find or load main class com.uwsoft.editor.LevelEditor`

Comment: Here's the complete path to the file:  E:\Software\Overlap2D_006\Overlap2D_unzipped\Overlap2D\com\uwsoft\editor\LevelEditor.class

Comment: This "e:\Software\Overlap2D_006\Overlap2D" != "E:\Software\Overlap2D_006\Overlap2D_unzipped\Overlap2D"

Comment: It's always the little things.  I had an error in my path above.  Once I had my coffee it was obvious.  Thanks for the help and the quick response, it's working just like you said.

Comment: @Shamrock88 Let this be a lesson to you then! **Coffee** *then* code.